# List Comprehension with list of lists

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I have problems to understand the following piece of code:

```
treePositions :: Tree a -> [[Int]]
treePositions (Node _ ts) =
    [] : [ (i : is ) | i <- [0..(length ts - 1)],
    is <- treePositions (index ts i) ]
```

This function would calculate any valid paths to a position in the given tree, where for every node the edges are marked with 0..lastOutgoingEdge. 
If I understood it right the index function would return the node at Index i in the node list of the tree.

```
index :: [a] -> Int -> a
index :: [a] -> Int -> a
index [] i = error "invalid index"
index (x:xs) 0 = x
index (x:xs) i = ith xs (i-1)
```

Now for given trees:

```
t1 = Node "a" [
        Node "b" [
            Node "c"[],
            Node "d"[]
        ]
     ]
t2 = Node "z" []
```

the function would return:

```
treePositions t1 == [ [], [0], [0,0], [0,1] ] 
treePositions t2 == [ [] ]
```

What I don't understand is this part:

`[] : [ (i : is ) | i <- [0..(length ts - 1)],is <- treePositions (index ts i) ]`

My thoughts:

If I have `x|x <- [0..10], x < 2`. This would translate in "take every x in `[0..10]` for which `x < 2` applies. So if I would take every i in `[0..(length ts - 1)]`, how would this then return lists for a condition?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your case, the part after the comma is not a condition, but a second generator. Simplified, the notation looks like this:

```
> [ (a, b) | a <- [1..3], b <- [1..2] ]
> [(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2),(3,1),(3,2)]
```

The example compherension above means the following:

1. go through list `[1..3]`, and for every element of it,
2. go through list `[1..2]`, and for every element of it,
3. produce a tuple

Further, a generator can depend on elements of previous generators, e.g.:

```
> [ (a, b) | a <- [1..3], b <- [1..a] ]
> [(1,1),(2,1),(2,2),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3)]
```

---

So in your case:

```
[ (i : is ) | i <- [0..(length ts - 1)],is <- treePositions (index ts i) ]
```

the logic is this:

1. for every `i` in `0..(length ts - 1)`,
2. go through every `is` in `treePositions (index ts i)`,
3. and produce `i : is` as result

Comment: thanks :) so if I would wanted to add a condition to the result I could do it like this for example: `[ (a, b) | a <- [1..3], b <- [1..2] , a < b]` ?